# Prove that the set $\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2\mid 2<x^2+y^2<4\}$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying to prove this in the following way:

Name the area between the two circles $S$

Suppose $(x,y) \in S$. Let $\delta = \min \{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2}\}$.

Then, I'm trying to show that $B_\delta(x,y) \subseteq S$, i.e: for $(u,v)$ in $B_\delta(x,y)$ it is true that $2<u^2+v^2<4$.

Is this approach right? How can I write this down and prove it in a formal matter?

Comment: Sounds like one correct approach. Should use $\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\sqrt{2}$ when you define your $\delta$, though. If that little ball was not included in your annulus $S$, pick a point that "witnesses" this, and use the _triangle inequality_ involving that point and $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$.

Comment: That´s it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The interval $(2,4)$ is open in $\Bbb R$, and the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is continuous, thus as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function, the said set is continuous.

Comment: It is possible that the relation between continuity and open sets is not yet known when you are told to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this more easily:

If $A$ and $B$ are opens, then $A\cap B$ is open.

note that 
$$S=B(0,4)\cap(\Bbb{R}^2- B[0,2]),$$

where $B(0,4)$ is the open ball in $(0,0)$ of radius $4$, and $B[0,2]$ the closed ball in $(0,0)$ with radius $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $u \in A$, where $A=\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} ; 2<x^2+y^2<4 \rbrace$ Let $r=\min \lbrace d(u,0) -2, 4-d(u,0) \rbrace$. It is not difficult to see that $B(u;r) \subset A$.